# Limitations of Apache's multi-threading while using sockets in PHP

Tags: php, apache, sockets, nginx

I have a PHP script that connects to a socket server and sends 1 packet of data, then closes the socket. Sending's timeout is set to 1 sec.

Let's say 150 users simultaneously access this script and the socket server is offline, triggering 1 second timeout for each user.

I assume Apache would start a worker for each user, each blocking resources for a second, and there may be limitations on the number of concurrent users. The ones who go overboard the limit would be queued, not just for this particular script, but for all scripts on the website. Is this assumption correct, and if so, what are possible ways to avoid the blockage?